# Actionscript 3 - find the coordinate of an edge of a movie clip

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I find say the left edge of a movie clip?

Comment: What do you mean by "edge"? Do you need x,y coordinates of the corner? And the answer depends on the registration point of the MovieClip, do you know beforehand where it is?

Comment: By edge I mean the x coordinate of the leftmost part of the clip, no matter what its shape is. The problem is the registration point and I don't know where it is on a given clip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using getBounds or getRect methods of display object: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getBounds() http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getRect()

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the movie clip position registration, which i believe defaults to its top left corner. All you have to do is get its `x` and `y` and then fiddle with adding its `width` and/or `height` to figure out what you need.

Comment: well that's the problem, I don't necessarily know the registration point, it may be anywhere in the clip and I need to find the leftmost edge, even if it's an irregular shape. Is that even possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you don't explicitly change it, then it's going to be the top left corner. We're talking dynamically created clips here, right?